# How to login from central domain to subdomain in angular using JWT?

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, jwt, single-sign-on

**I want to implement a feature in which there is a central login site lets say: *https://example.com* , and when user enter login credentials in this page and select from dropdown on which sub domain user wants to log into, the user gets logged into that subdomain like *https://abc.example.com*.**
I am using MEAN stack and jwt token for authentication. JWT implementation is applied in standard way in which first: request is sent to "*/authenticate*" and then token is returned which will be stored in browser local storage.
I have successfully done one site authentication ie. login from *https://example.com* and logging user in that domain, but now 
**I want to implement like this flow =>**

**On login page of https://example.com :**

1. User can select an option from drop down in which subdomain to login
2. After that user enters login credentials ( these credentials can be different or same for all subdomains )
3. User gets redirected to dashboard page of that subdomain ( with JWT token stored in the local storage of that selected sub domain )

*Above is the flow I want to be implemented but can be changed if other flow achieves the same result*

**I have searched questions and blogs regarding this topic:**

I have gone through SSO ... but that is not what exactly I want; because SSO is like login in one subdomain and it gets logged in everywhere else... but I want to login from a single login page to subdomain's dashboard page based on user selection.

**How I have thought of implementing this (not working) :**
I will first send "/authenticate" request to *https://example.com* with parameter like 
`{ username: "alice", password: "****", subDomainUrl: "https://abc.example.com"}`

 My nodejs backend will authenticate and return me the JWT token. Now I will redirect to that subdomain(*https://abc.example.com*) and send this token from *https://example.com* to *https://abc.example.com* and somehow it will get stored in this subdomain's(https://abc.example.com) localstorage. After it is stored in local storage I can easily do my other work. 
So how to implement this? Is the above approach practical; if then how to properly do it? What is the best way to implement these kind of architectures? Any help will be great, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you  first send /authenticate request from https://example.com/.
It will be validated by nodejs backend and then generate JWT token and redirect to the new subdomain including token.

```
http.get('*',function(req,res){  
    res.redirect('https://abc.example.com?token='+JWTtoken);
})
```

You can fetch the token from the subdomain and store in your local storage. Further, you can use this token for your api authentication.

Comment: What in case when user log in on example.com, then open new tab in a browser and manually type abc.example.com ?  A user will not be logged in, but it should as he already logged in on example.com. Even more: what is case when a user log in on abc.example.com and then open a new tab with manually typed example.com address?